# Central db with satelites

Tags: mysql, service-broker

I am facing the following challenge.
I want to have a central MySql server having all the data and several satellites servers that hold part of the data.

Satellites servers will hold some original data which should be inserted at the central server. Something like this:
[image]

For other tables I need to have a two way sync. Something like this:
[image]

Of course any time I want to be able to add another server(station 4).
   Also because network is not 100% guaranteed I need to have asynchronous communication.
I know that I could make my services that could do the job I am just looking if there is a ready solution.
I have found that for MS-SQL they suggest to use the service broker, but I need something for mySQL, if is a tool that can do the job

Comment: Some other Questions on this Forum discuss unconventional replication setups.  There is nothing standard; good luck; it won't be easy.